# If I get COVID-19, can I get cured by myself?

Tags: infection, immune-system, covid-19, virus, recovery

Suppose I get infected by COVID-19.

I am a healthy person but with weight issues, according to the *standard weight tables*.

Can my immune system cure me by itself? That is, without the need of medications or drugs? and by only resting and eating healthy?

I have read this page

https://www.healthline.com/health/coronavirus-treatment#when-to-seek-care

> If you’re young and healthy with only mild symptoms, your doctor will likely advise you to isolate yourself at home and to limit contact with others in your household. You’ll likely be advised to rest, stay well hydrated, and to closely monitor your symptoms.

then it says

> If your symptoms worsen with home care, it’s important to get prompt medical care.

Here, Why could symptoms worsen?

Answer (score 6):

> If you’re young and healthy with only mild symptoms, your doctor will likely advise you to isolate yourself at home and to limit contact with others in your household. You’ll likely be advised to rest, stay well hydrated, and to closely monitor your symptoms.

This means that if you have mild symptoms, yes, you will eventually "cure" yourself, the same way you would recover from a typical common cold, or how a healthy individual would typically handle influenza.

> If your symptoms worsen with home care, it’s important to get prompt medical care.

This means if you have bad symptoms, then home care is not enough, and you need the assistance that a hospital can provide. There is still no *cure* that medical care can provide; instead, the purpose of getting care is to prevent your symptoms from killing you before your immune system can handle the infection on its own. For some this includes mechanical ventilation: using a machine to help you breathe.

Comment: Thank you Bryan Krause for your answer, it's practically a relief. I wonder why don't I see this information on TV news!

Comment: @user8473907 Maybe you need to watch different TV news :) - this information is widely available.

Comment: right. What TV news do you watch?

Comment: BTW regarding my question at the bottom of the post?

Comment: @user8473907 I mostly get general news from print sources (some of which also use other media), including NPR, the BBC, the New York Times, and the Washington Post. As far as what causes symptoms to be worse in some people, it isn't clear yet. Older individuals are certainly more susceptible, as are those with certain preexisting conditions. Interactions between age and preexisting conditions aren't understood yet - this was mentioned in comments here, too: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/why-would-someone-healthy-and-10-39-years-old-infected-with-covid-19-might-die

Comment: Thanks for the news suggestion :). Yes, but I am not referring to the case where the person is old or the person has a disease, I'm referring to the opposite case. But, you know, I think it's fine. You said in your answer that in any case they **will** recover.

Comment: @America No, he said they will recover **if they have mild symptoms**. Young, healthy people have died of COVID-19.

Comment: @CareyGregory got it. Yes, now I know about that "Young, healthy people have died of COVID-19." I confirmed that info thanks to you; although still doesn't makes sense and probably will never make sense to me.